# What is the Java equivalent of Groovy's class 'Message'?

Tags: java, xml, groovy

I want to implement a Groovy Script in Java Code. The Script get's an XML document which carries the order comment of a customer in the Node "sapCpiOutboundOrderComments". This node has two Nodes "SAPCpiOutboundOrderComment" because the customers have the option to write two comments for the order. Problem: The comments are only processed correct, if the aren't longer than 131 characters. So what the Script does, it splits the comments from both "SAPCpiOutboundOrderComment" to smaller pieces. That's probably not relevant for my question, but I didn't want to leave out the background.

So, what I'm wondering about is: What is the Java equivalent of Groovy's class 'Message'? It should allow me to receive XML-documents and return XML-documents from methods.

I know there's a class 'com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.message.Message', an interface 'com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.writer.document.Message' and an interface 'com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.Message'. But maybe there are other Options? If not, does someone know, which one of the three is the equivalent?

Comment: You should not directly use any of these classes and interfaces as the "internal" package already indicates they're used internally and might change or be removed. If you want to handle XML documents in Java have a look at libraries such as JAXB or the more low level SAX/StAX.

Comment: Which Groovy `Message` class are you talking about?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't know there are several, it basically only should handle XML

Comment: It is pretty hard to suggest something if you don't know what it should replace. I mean, I could just suggest `org.w3c.dom.Document`, but then I wonder why Groovy wouldn't use that directly, which suggests it is probably not a suitable replacement.

Comment: Groovy based on java. And any groovy class is a java class. No need to search for substitution - you could use it from java.

Comment: Well there doesn't appear to be a `Message` class in the Groovy class library that handles XML.  (There is only this:  https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/messages/Message.html) Are you talking about a `Message` class from some 3rd-party library?

Comment: btw, as soon as there is SAP and CPI mentioned in question - i guess the Message class is this one: 
`com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message` - https://help.sap.com/doc/a56f52e1a58e4e2bac7f7adbf45b2e26/Cloud/en-US/com/sap/gateway/ip/core/customdev/util/Message.html)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Well the script takes a 'Message'-object, which represents a XML-document.

@daggett Thanks, I'll also have a look at this approach

@StephenC Yes it's probably the class `com.sap.gateway.ip.core.customdev.util.Message` that @daggett suggested. But I doubt, that you have that class in the sript environment under control

Comment: If that is the class, then in Java you'd use the exact same class. This is not a "Groovy class", this is a class from a SAP library.